# Wordpress Cron phpmailerexception

Tags: php, wordpress, email, cron

I have a wordpress site which has installed EasySMTP plugin.

I have a real cron task and I have unactive wp simulated cron.

My cron is running, but inside it I want to make a mail send and is not working.

In my log, I see this:

```
[20-Apr-2017 14:46:02 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Invalid address:  (setFrom) wordpress@[domain]' in /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php:1023
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php(352): PHPMailer->setFrom('wordpress@[domain...', 'WordPress', false)
#1 /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/innovation-factory/includes/php/functions.php(350): wp_mail('msolla@domain...', 'Tienes 1 ideas ...', '\n\t\t<html>\n\t\t<bo...', Array)
#2 /home/user/public_html/wp-content/plugins/innovation-factory/innovation-factory.php(301): enviarNotificacion('msolla@domain...', 'Tienes 1 ideas ...', NULL, Array, '\n\t\t<html>\n\t\t<bo...')
#3 [internal function]: do_this_hourly()
#4 /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): call_user_func_array('do_this_hourly', Array)
#5 /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#6 /home/des in /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php on line 1023
```

Obviusly I have other smtp configuration in EasySMTP. In fact, I have an smtp hosted in other server with other domain diferent to de web page domain.

If I call do_this_hourly() function out of the cron, it sends correctly the emails. I need do something different to mail in cron tasks? Maybe that wp-cron.php not load EasySMTP yet?

My cron is programmed with this command:

```
php /home/user/public_html/wp-cron.php
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to come from the fact that $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is not set when mail is sent using cron via crontab, cli or some other command line script.

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` throws a notice, `$sitename` is an empty string, and `$from_email` is simply 'wordpress@'.

WordPress does at least give you a chance to set the `$from_email` before it attempts to send, in which case I've added a filter which seems to work for me.

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', function( $from_email ) {
    // Domain ends with an @. Append the domain from the site url.
    if ( substr( $from_email, -1 ) === '@' ) {
        // Trim protocol, double forward slash, preceeding www, port, and remaind of request uri.
        $from_email .= preg_replace( '#^(?:[hftps]*:)?//(?:www\.)?|[:/?].*$#i', '', get_site_url() );
    }
    return $from_email;
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

$_SER
the problem is, that php doesn't get the $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_NAME' ] when executed via crontab. And that's why the phpmailer throws that exception.

I solved it by passing the variable manually in crontab. F.e:

```
*/15 * * * * export SERVER_NAME="server.domain.name" && php /var/www/clients/client2/web8/web/wp-base/wp-cron.php
```

A detailed description of this problem can be found here https://www.ask-sheldon.com/wordpress-cron-using-wp_mail-function/.

Comment: I finnally solved it creating cron.php file on the root of my wp installation and doing my stuff outside wordpress. Is not a good way, but is the only that I can do it work.